# Custom search form and query for wordpress site

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I've created the following widget which creates a custom search form with filters as well as an accompanying query:

```
class Custom_Search_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'custom_search_widget',
            'description' => 'Custom Search Widget with Checkboxes'
        );
        parent::__construct( 'custom_search_widget', 'Custom Search Widget', $widget_ops );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // widget frontend output
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];
        ?>

        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <div style="position: relative; margin-top:10px;">
                <input type="text" style="width:100%; border-radius:5px; height:2rem;" name="s" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post" />

                <div class="checkboxes" style="margin-top:1rem;">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="270" <?php echo ( isset($_GET['category']) && in_array('270', $_GET['category']) ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Chiropractic News</label><br>

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="classifieds" value="1" <?php echo ( isset( $_GET['classifieds'] ) && $_GET['classifieds'] == 1 ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Classifieds</label><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="schools" value="1" <?php echo ( isset( $_GET['schools'] ) && $_GET['schools'] == 1 ) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Colleges/Schools</label><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="271"> Everything Else</label>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" style="position: absolute; top: 11%; right: 5px; transform: translateY(-50%); background: transparent; border: none;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }


    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // update widget settings
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        // widget settings form
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php
    }

}

function register_custom_search_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Custom_Search_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_custom_search_widget' );

function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search && isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $tax_query = array();
        $post_type_query = array( 'post' );

        if ( isset( $_GET['category'] ) ) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $_GET['category']
            );
        }

        if ( isset( $_GET['classifieds'] ) && $_GET['classifieds'] == 1 ) {
            $post_type_query = array( 'gd_equipment', 'gd_services', 'gd_jobs', 'gd_classifieds', 'gd_practices', 'gd_colleges' );
            $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type_query );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_GET['schools'] ) && $_GET['schools'] == 1 ) {
            $post_type_query = array( 'gd_colleges' );
            $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type_query );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            return;
        }
        
        if ( isset( $_GET['else'] ) && $_GET['else'] == 1 ) {
            $post_type_query = array( 'post' );
            $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type_query );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            return;
        }

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type_query );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_query' );
```

My issue is with the query, as it's more restrictive than it should be (I'm looking for multiple checkboxes to make for a more broad search)

Right now, if I search the word "Table" and only select 'Classifieds' I get hundreds of legitimate results. If I search with 'CHiropractic News' I get about 25. If I select news and classifieds I get none. Nothing would ever fall into both selections as the post type for classifieds would never overlap with the news category ID, but I want it to be an aggregate. So if both are selected I would get ALL results from both news and classifieds

I can't seem to figure out where the issue is here